# Is it possible to restart the facial recognition within the Windows Photos app?

Tags: windows-10, photos, windows-photo-viewer

I like the facial recognition feature introduced into the Photos app in Windows 10; however, something is causing it to fail occasionally, and on restarting the app, indexing does not continue.

Deleting the database file at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\MediaDb.v1.sqlite` does make it start form scratch again, but with in excess of 55000 pictures for it to first find, and then index, this is taking a long time to run, and is dying horribly leaving the app in a position where it consumes a lot of CPU time but doesn't actually do anything beyond showing the photos.

Is there any way to restart the indexing, beyond destroying the database?

Comment: I just tried disabling facial recognition and making sure photos has had time to complete all of the other tasks like photo/video thumbnail generation. Re-enabled facial recognition and it doesn't seem to kick on. Even re-indexing doesn't seem to work on large data sets. I wish Microsoft would simply add a 'start facial recognition' button somewhere with a progress bar.

Comment: @RowlandShaw how many gigs of photos are you getting the facial recognition feature to work with before it freezes up? Can you try incrementally?

Comment: I've got about 490Gb of photos in my OneDrive, so it takes several weeks to get through them all (as it takes about a second per image, and its only indexing whist the PC is on, and even then, it'll stop after a while if left unattended)

Answer (score 1):

**What Setting is there to reset facial recognition within the Microsoft Photos app?**

1. Turn off and back on Peoples setting in Microsoft Photos App

- Open Photos.
- Click on three dots in top right.
- Open Settings.
- Turn off the People option where is says:

> People
>
> Allow people in your photos and videos to be named and grouped
> and for this data to be stored on your device by turning on face
> detection and recognition.

- and Wait or Reboot.
- Repeat and turn back on, wait for re-indexing.

[Source](https://winaero.com/face-detection-recognition-photos-windows-10/)

---

**Why is Microsoft Photos App Not Doing What I Want?**

Unfortunately most the fixes found for various Microsoft Photos App problems seem to take more of a systematic/ drastic approach of seeing if there is any corruption or problems that are causing the underlying issues to begin with.

For many of the procedure you may need to **reboot**, to see if the issue is resolved.

There is hope, one user [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-photos/photos-app-face-recognition-and-naming-people/f7eb7d8d-e416-49ec-b628-0b7b77467dd3?tab=AllReplies&page=4) has indexed 85 Gig of photos with the app.

---

2. Can this be replicated on another machine? This is a good way to rule out many things.

---

3. Does the computer have lots of Ram and SSD Harddrive? This is a very heavy program.

---

4. Check that the default location for photos is set.

- Open File, Explorer Click Libraries on the left of File Explorer.
- Right-click Pictures and select Properties
- In the bottom right select Restore
- Defaults, Apply, OK.

---

5. Check App Permissions to rule out conflicting settings:

- Go to the Privacy page to choose which apps can use a particular feature.
- Select Start  > Settings  > Privacy.
- Select the Photos app and select app permissions as on.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/app-permissions-aea98a7c-b61a-1930-6ed0-47f0ed2ee15c)

---

6. Check for App Updates

- Open Store App, Click three-dotted menu on top right,
- select downloads and updates option.
- Click Get Updates, if any available, apply.

---

7. Try Repairing App

- Open Start > Settings > Apps > Apps & features
- Scroll down to Photos
- Select it
- Click Advanced options
- Click Repair

---

8. Try Resetting App

- Open Start > Settings > Apps > Apps & features
- Scroll down to Photos
- Select it
- Click Advanced options
- Click Reset

---

9. Try With and Without Photos App Addon

To Remove

- Settings app > Apps
- Click on the Photos app
- Click Advanced options link.
- See the Photos.DLC.Main entry
- Click on the same to see Uninstall button.
- Click the Uninstall button and then
- Click the Uninstall button again when you see the confirmation dialog to remove the Photos Add-on.
- Remove

To get Photos App Addon

- Store Link: [Photos App Addon](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/photos-add-on/9pggj4lf6spv?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0&rtc=1&activetab=pivot:reviewstab)

[Source One](https://web.archive.org/web/20180603043154/http://www.intowindows.com:80/download-photos-add-on-for-photos-app-in-windows-10/)  and [Source Two](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/photos-app-face-recognition-and-naming-people/f7eb7d8d-e416-49ec-b628-0b7b77467dd3?page=4)

---

10. If still not working, close app and go to:

    `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState`

and delete all files there in and reboot [this folder is also removed during uninstall and reinstall].

[Source 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-photos/photo-app-in-windows-10-stopped-working/95fd096c-9c2e-45ea-8a58-ca29fedae9f3) and [Source 2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-photos-winpc/windows-10-photos-app-not-working/e8be2a12-fead-4976-9e73-48519cefde16)

---

11. Try Uninstalling the App and Reinstalling

- Use the grid view and select the Photos App
- Use elevated powershell; For a single user enter:

  `Get-AppxPackage | Out-GridView -Passthru | Remove-AppXPackage`
- Or for all users

  `Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Out-GridView -PassThru | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online`
- Tick the Photos App / Click OK to Uninstall /  Reboot.
- To install from computer cache to all users go:

  `Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.Windows.Photos | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}`
- Or download new version of [Microsoft Photos](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-photos/9wzdncrfjbh4) from the App Store, Install.
- Reboot and Check.

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/942418/how-do-you-forcefully-remove-apps-in-windows-10/987227#987227)

---

12. Are you giving enough time?

- After reinstall, or deleting cache allow the program some hours to re-index.

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-photos/photos-app-face-recognition-and-naming-people/f7eb7d8d-e416-49ec-b628-0b7b77467dd3?tab=AllReplies&page=4)

---

13. Elevate CMD run System file Checker

    `sfc /scannow`

[Use the System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e)

---

14. If Fails: Run Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) from elevated cmd one at a time:

- `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth`
- `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`
- `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

[Source 1](https://appuals.com/use-dism-repair-windows-10/) and [Source 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism)

---

15. If fails get matching windows image and run DISM again, [instructions here](https://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/) or [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image).

---

16. Windows Registry Checker Tool (Scanreg.exe)

- Backup Registery
- Open elevated cmd and run:
- `scanreg /fix`

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-windows-registry-checker-tool-scanreg-exe-aaae4323-daa2-8477-5a4e-2a273779fdf0)

---

17. Editing Registry looking for duplicate values are found:

> - Log on to your PC as administrator.
> - Click Win key + R, type regedit, and press Enter.
> - Use the left pane and navigate to the [below] directory:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\LocalSettings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\Repository\Families Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

> - Here you should see several entries each of which has a version number, for example, Microsoft.Windows.Photos_15.1201.10020.0_ or
>   similar. If this folder contains 8 Microsoft Windows Photos App
>   entries, it means that the outdated registry keys have been left
>   intact after the application update. Therefore, the outdated keys have
>   to be removed. (In some cases, people have 4 entries, two of which are
>   outdated. In this case, the old two should also be removed.)
> - Select the outdated entry, right-click on it, and open Properties.
> - Select Security and open Permissions tab.
> - Click Advanced in Select User or Group window.
> - Select Find Now, pick your user name, and click OK. Steps 5-8 explain how to take the property of the obsolete entry.
> - Without doing so, you won’t be allowed to delete the outdated entries.
> - Once done, right-click on the outdated entry and select Delete.
> - Repeat the same steps with each four outdated Windows Photos Apps’ entries.
> - Finally, close everything and reboot your PC.

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/photo-and-videos-will-not-open/5fa73513-13c4-4f10-89e2-ed289a49aa4d)

---

18. Run App Troubleshooter

> - Run troubleshooter for Microsoft Store apps:
> - Select the Start  button > Settings  > Update & Security
> - Troubleshoot > Windows Store Apps > Run the Troubleshooter.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/fix-problems-with-apps-from-microsoft-store-93ed0bcf-9c12-3df6-6dda-92ec5d0415ac)

---

19. Review Microsoft Forum Postings

- [Apps on Windows 10, Photos](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-photos?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1)

---

20. Lodge Feedback with Microsoft:

- Press `Windows Key + F` to open Feedback Hub
- Sign in to Microsoft Account so that you can track your feedback.
- Under settings in lower corner there is some additional diagnostic settings.
- Be sure to Add Screen Shots and all information for a single idea, so that the problem can be reproduced.
- Send Feedback
- Click Share, copy link
- Create new forum post (see points below to choose forum) and paste link as part of question with all information.

  ```
   - ***Send a different feedback per problem, don't combine them.***
   - **Don't overlook the feedback hub**, as this is the way Microsoft knows it is getting feedback from its real Windows 10 users, and can properly track your questions on the forums.
  ```

[Source 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-photos/photos-app-face-recognition-and-naming-people/f7eb7d8d-e416-49ec-b628-0b7b77467dd3?page=3), [Source 2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-photos/new-windows-10-photo-app/5c52a460-6812-4ab6-819a-10646a23a5cd)

---

21. Ask a Question on Microsoft Forum

    - Lodge Question [Here](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1611902960&rver=6.7.6643.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/site/completesignin?silent=False&returnUrl=https%253A%252F%252Fanswers.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252Fnewthread%253Fthreadtype%253DQuestions%2526cancelurl%253D%252Fen-us%252Fwindows%252Fforum%252Fapps_windows_10-photos%253Ftab%253DThreads%2526forum%253Dwindows%2526filter%253Dapps_windows_10-photos&id=273572&aadredir=1)

      - Post a Question
      - Category: Windows
      - Windows Version: Apps on Windows 10
      - Windows Topics: Photos
      - Use link from feedback in section 20.

---

22. Join the Windows Insider Program

> - With the Windows Insider Program, you’ll get all the latest Windows 10 builds as soon as they’re available. [more info here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/join-the-windows-insider-program-ef20bb3d-40f4-20cc-ba3c-a72c844b563c)

- Join Windows Insider Program [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-photos/new-windows-10-photo-app/5c52a460-6812-4ab6-819a-10646a23a5cd)
- There is a range of programs that users get to access and test.
- Microsoft Photos may be posted here again for peer review testing (as it has before), get involved and help shape the app.
- When the photos app comes up for peer review; there is its own forum section for insider. Submission can be made [here](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1611902960&rver=6.7.6643.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/site/completesignin?silent=False&returnUrl=https%253A%252F%252Fanswers.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252Fnewthread%253Fthreadtype%253DQuestions%2526cancelurl%253D%252Fen-us%252Fwindows%252Fforum%252Fapps_windows_10-photos%253Ftab%253DThreads%2526forum%253Dwindows%2526filter%253Dapps_windows_10-photos&id=273572&aadredir=1).

  - Post a Question
  - Category: Windows Insider Program
  - Products: Apps on Insider Preview
  - Topics and apps: Photos
  - PC or phone: PC
  - Use link from feedback in section 20.

Example of prior listing of Photos App on Insider [here](https://www.onmsft.com/news/fast-ring-windows-insiders-get-updated-photos-app-with-new-image-editing-ui).

---

23. Microsoft Developer Feedback Site

Also there is a developer feedback site also [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190828171724/https://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

> Consumer suggestions for Windows and Windows Phone are usually closed
> as being in the wrong forum - you should be posted via the Windows
> Feedback app (available on all Windows 10 devices)

Read through the posts, there may be existing threads, or you may be fortunate and find other users and your self gain traction with your request, which results in more timely development of the apps capacity issues for example.

---

24. Set Priority of the App to Real-Time

Due to the heavy load of your work, and the app is not working as you would like, it might be worth try changing the priority of the program, see its effect.

> Windows shares processor resources between all running processes based
> upon their priority level. If a process (application) has a higher
> priority level, it gets more processor resources for better
> performance compared to a process having lower priority.

- Open Task Manager as Admin
- Click on the details tab
- Right click go to Microsoft.Photos.exe
- Right Click -> Set Priority -> Realtime (or High)

[Source One](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/89548-set-cpu-process-priority-applications-windows-10-a.html), [Source Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663993/what-is-the-realtime-process-priority-setting-for)

---

**Final Thoughts**

On the question of 50,000 plus photos, if the above have not fixed the problem,  it may be that the program is not perfected yet, or simply they have focused the higher demands via the Azure Cognitive Services.

They may have neglected higher demands in the Microsoft Photos App while focusing more on its common user use, and working towards increasing its capacity in the future.

So likely without feature requests they will not test and produce the program to work as the users would like, under higher demands, rather leaving this for big business building there own applications and web services privately, as there have not been much request for it. Please see points 19, 20, 21, 22 and 23 to get involved.

---

**Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services looking at Face Recognition.**

- Microsoft have made available the facial recognition services for a cost via the Azure API...

Jim Bennet noted [noted](https://www.jimbobbennett.io/face-identification-with-azure-faceapi/):

> For the pricing tier, there is a free tier called F0 that gives you
> 30,000 calls per month at a rate of no more than 20 per minute, and
> you can have one face resource per subscription with this tier. After
> this there is a paid tier limited to 10 calls per second and you pay
> per 1,000 calls - at the time of writing this is US$0.25 per 1,000
> calls.

Here is his sample [face app](https://github.com/jimbobbennett/FaceFinder) using the api on Github.

**Information on Cognitive Services API**

- [Microsoft - Try Cognitive Services - Face API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/?api=face-api)
- [Microsoft -  AI School - Face API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/ai/ai-school)
- [Microsoft - What is the Azure Face API?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/overview?wt.mc_id=mobilecontentmoderation-blog-jabenn)
- [Microsoft - Tutorial: Create a WPF app to display face data in an image](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/ive-got-a-powershell-secret-adding-a-gui-to-scripts/)
- [Microsoft - Sample: Explore an image processing app with C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Face/Tutorials/FaceAPIinCSharpTutorial)
- [Microsoft - Get face detection data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtodetectfacesinimage)
- [Microsoft - What is the Azure Face API?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/overview)

**Sample Apps and Code**

- [github - Microsoft Face API: Windows Client Library & Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Windows)
- [Implementation Of Face API Using Microsoft Azure And Visual Studio](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-a-face-api-using-microsazure/)
- [Powershell Module for Microsoft Cognitive Services](https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2016/07/08/powershell-module-for-microsoft-congnitive-services/)
- [Microsoft FamilyNotes sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-familynotes)

---

**Further Reading:**

- [SU - A Simple Analysis of What (Local) Data the Photos App in Windows 10 Collects](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/8zk1yy/a_simple_analysis_of_what_local_data_the_photos/)
- [SU - Where Does the Windows 10 Photos App Store its Catalog Files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1240953/where-does-the-windows-10-photos-app-store-its-catalog-files)

Comment: None of those solutions work

Comment: Point 10 was the option I've had to do, as mentioned in the question

Comment: I'd already determined that the sqllite files was the minimal step to destroy the index and start again - I'm after a solution that can recover a damaged index. As a side note, changing the process priority does little to help (it seems to not be multi-threaded enough)